# How to store Id cards of participants in a cloud in hyperledger composer?

Tags: nodes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In hyperledger composer every time an id is issued to any participant than it gets stored in ~/.composer/card directory in local machine. but I want to store them, on a cloud. is there any way in which I can achieve this? I am developing an application based on hyperledger fabric using hyperledger-composer. And while registering a participant an id is issued to the participant. So, the .card file is created in projects root directory while the imported card gets stored in ~/.composer/card in my machine. And to develope this application I am using Node APIs of hyperledger-composer.

below is the code for issuing the id card to a participant:-

```
async function issueIdentity() {
try {
    var id = 'org.exchange.network.User#user01';
    let issueOptions = {
        card: admin@my-network,
        file: user01,
        newUserId: user01,
        participantId: id
    };
    await IdentityIssue.handler(issueOptions);
    let importOptions = {
        file:'user01.card',
        card: 'user01@hyperledger-exchange'
    };
    await CardImport.handler(importOptions);
} catch (error) {
    return error;
}
```

}

Comment: You need read the relevant page in the Hyperledger Composer docs that describes cloud based storage and cloud wallets -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/cloud-wallets

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony I have already worked around it and it didn't worked for me.I did exactly as told in the docs but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

if your network is deployed to a cloud environment then you can look at cloud wallets to store your network cards since you can't access them like you would on a local machine.

you can see the information on the subject here:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/business-network/cloud-wallets

I am using IBM cloud for example and it has support for such things, it's quite straight forward to create cards in a cloud wallet and then use them to create APIs against them.

another good read is this one : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-blockchain-starter-plan-network/index.html

Comment: I tried using IBM cloud as suggested in docs but still card are going in local machine instead of cloud.

Comment: added another article link which shows you how to set the cloud services required